# How can I find a specific string within a path using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, path

I have the following path:

```
/s/STRINGINEED/abcdef/
```

How should I structure my regex to match `STRINGINEED` as a result?

`/s/` is a fixed path, so I would like to get any string between `/s/` and the  following `/`.

Comment: `'/s/STRINGINEED/abcdef/'.split('/')[2]` ?

Comment: using capture group regex: `'/s/STRINGINEED/abcdef/'.match(/\/s\/(.*?)\//)[1]`

Comment: using lookbehind and lookahead regex: `'/s/STRINGINEED/abcdef/'.match(/(?<=\/s\/).*?(?=\/)/)[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might execute:

```
\/s\/([^\/]*)
```

and then use the first group matched.

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/MaGIlD/2

Answer (score 4):

To get the `string` coming after `/s/` in the path, you can use [the following **regex**](https://regex101.com/r/i5rNHb/2):

```
\/s\/([\w]+)\/
```

**Demo:**

```js
const regex = /\/s\/([\w\d]+)\//gm;
const str = `/s/STRINGINEED/abcdef/`;

console.log(regex.exec(str)[1]);
```

---

Another option is to use **[`.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**:

```
str.split('/s/')[1].split("/")[0]
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = '/s/STRINGINEED/abcdef/';
console.log(str.split('/s/')[1].split("/")[0]);
```

Comment: @deeJ You are welcome, glad it helps.